# Instagram embed code from url (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, instagram, instagram-api

In my application, I would like to allow user introduce a url of instagram, and then automatically retrieve the embed code of it.

I found this reference:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/#oembed

When I try the given example (https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN) in my Chrome browser, I get the json with the code I am looking for.

However, if I try this from the rails console:

```
Net::HTTP.get_response(URI("https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN"))
```

I get this:

```
#<Net::HTTPMovedPermanently 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY readbody=true>
```

I saw that instagram have a new API, but I don't want to make user authenticate from instagram.

**Is there a way to do it?**

Comment: So it redirects?  The response should return the redirect location, what do you get it you follow the redirect?

Comment: There is no redirection url in the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Following+Redirection)

```
def fetch(uri_str, limit = 10)
  # You should choose a better exception.
  raise ArgumentError, 'too many HTTP redirects' if limit == 0

  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(uri_str))

  case response
  when Net::HTTPSuccess then
    response
  when Net::HTTPRedirection then
    location = response['location']
    warn "redirected to #{location}"
    fetch(location, limit - 1)
  else
    response.value
  end
end

str = "https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN"
response = fetch(str)
redirected to https://api.instagram.com/publicapi/oembed/?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN
redirected to https://www.instagram.com/publicapi/oembed/?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN
redirected to https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=http://instagr.am/p/fA9uwTtkSN
=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>

response.body
=> # JSON response
```

So just follow the redirects.

Comment: Looks like they've not finished implementing the api, it's weird you get redirected to the initial url which give you the response eventually.

Comment: @guyaloni yeah, incredibly strange.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [oembed gem](https://sul.im/oembed) by [soulim](https://github.com/soulim). nice and clean way to get embed code

In case of instagram it goes like

include following line in your gem file

```
gem 'oembed'
```

next

```
bundle install
```

create a helper class

```
class InstaApi
  include Oembed::Client

  def endpoint_uri
    'http://api.instagram.com/oembed'
  end
end
```

Now you can use

```
instClient = InstaApi.new
info = instClient.fetch('http://instagr.am/p/BUG/')
```

to Get your embed code

```
embed_code = info["html"]
```

Comment: oembed gem link is broken

Comment: it looks like the author archived the repo.
try out this one https://github.com/ruby-oembed/ruby-oembed